# Make advanced MVC Route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I’ve a website that contains two main dynamic modules:

1-      Module (1): To able the website admin from managing the whole website pages’ static content, he is able from adding a parent pages and child up to 2 levels

2-      Module (2): To able the website admin from managing the news’ articles that should be published to the website

For the routing, we’re planning to make it as following:

1-      Module (1)

www.websitename.com/parentpage

www.websitename.com/parentpage/childpage

www.websitename.com/parentpage/childpage/childchildpage

2-      Module (2)

www.websitename.com/news/newstitle

The problem here is module(2) routing not handled or executed never. I think because its conflicts here with the second scenario in module(1).

Any suggestions or recommendations?

Best Regards,

shady

Comment: you can use a static parameter in your routes to define them and resist conflicts in your Routes.

Comment: It would be good to see some of your related routeConfig file.

Comment: thank you, I have solved this problem using `RouteBase`

Comment: You can accept your own answer... so that it won't show up in the 'unanswered' tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help. I have solved this problem using `RouteBase`

```
 public class MyUrlRoute : RouteBase
{
    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        //Route Code
    }

    public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
    {
        //Virtual Path Code
    }
}
```

In RouteConfig

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.Add(new MyUrlRoute()); // Add before your default Routes
    defaults: new { language = "en", controller = "Home", action = "Home" },
    namespaces: new string[] { "Solution.Website.Controllers" }
    );
}
```